How to stop a composable function to fire while navigating?
I have a very simple app:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Navigation(
                    navController = rememberNavController()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

With two screens:
sealed class Screen(val route: String){
    data object MainScreen : Screen("main_screen")
    data object DetailScreen : Screen("detail_screen")

    fun withArgs(vararg args: String) = buildString {
        append(route)
        args.forEach { arg ->
            append("/$arg")
        }
    }
}

What I want is to pass a text from one screen to the other using navigation:
@Composable
fun Navigation(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = MainScreen.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = MainScreen.route
        ) {
            MainScreen(
                navigateToDetailScreen = { text ->
                    navController.navigate(DetailScreen.withArgs(text))
                }
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = DetailScreen.route + "/{text}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("text") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )
        ) { entry ->
            DetailScreen(
                text = entry.arguments?.getString("text")!!
            )
        }
    }
}

And here are my two screens:
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navigateToDetailScreen: (text: String) -> Unit
) {
    Log.d("MyTag", "MainScreen")

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                text = it
            }
        )
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navigateToDetailScreen(text)
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Navigate"
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailScreen(text: String) {
    Log.d("MyTag", "DetailScreen")

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text
        )
    }
}

The two problems I'm facing are:

Each time I write a new character inside the TextField, the MainScreen fun fires again and again.

When I press Navigate, the MainScreen fun fires again, the DetailScreen fires once and the MainScreen fun fires again resulting in displaying:
MainScreen //when the app starts
MainScreen //when adding the first character
MainScreen //when adding the second character
MainScreen //when clicking the "Navigate" button
DetailScreen //when the second screen is displayed
MainScreen //For no reason



How to stop that from happening?

I dont think log is a accurate way to check if a composable is recomposed. Try using the layout inspector to check for recomposition. Because the function may be executed but it must have been skipped the recomposition

Recomposition doesn’t necessarily mean that the UI has changed; it’s just a request to re-evaluate the composable to see if anything needs to be updated. Not all recompositions result in actual UI updates. Sometimes recompositions are triggered but then discarded due to some optimization
Because of this, if you place a log statement directly inside your composable, it will be executed every time the composable is recomposed. This can lead to a large number of log entries, which might make it seem like your UI is being rebuilt or re-created multiple times, even if that’s not the case.
Prefer using LaunchedEffect or SideEffect
